# Why does my Kadane's algorithm code give an output of 0 for all cases?

Tags: c, arrays, kadanes-algorithm

This is the code I wrote for finding the maximum sum subarray using Kadane's algorithm.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int maxSum(int a[],int size)
        {
            int ans=0;  //stores the final sum
            int sum=0;  //stores the sum of the elements in the empty array
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
                if(sum<0)
                {
                    sum=0;
                }
                if(ans<sum)
                {
                    ans=sum;
                }
            }
            return ans;
        }
        void main(){
            int j,size,t,total; //size=size of the array,t=number of test cases
            scanf("%d\n",&t);
            while(t-->0)
            {
                int a[size];
                for(j=0;j<size;j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d ",&a[j]);
                }
                total=maxSum(a,size);
                printf("\n%d",total);
            }
        }
```

I keep getting the wrong output:

For Input:

```
2 //test cases  
3 //case 1  
1 2 3  
4 //case 2  
-1 -2 -3 -4
```

Your Output is:

```
0 //it should be 6  
0 //it should be -1
```

Answer (score 4):

The only error is you haven't initialized `size` before using it to define the size of the array `a` - otherwise program is fine.

**MAJOR-->** It seems you are coding it on *Turbo* (as you have used `void main()` rather than `int main(void)`) which is an outdated compiler - shift to **GCC** or **CLANG**.

Comment: No, he is obviously not using Turbo C, otherwise `int a[size];` would not have compiled.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I haven't used it much, I guessed it as `void main()` has been used. Thanks!

Comment: But I have declared size in the main () function and passed it as an argument to the maxSum () function. Moreover, I tried using int main() as well, but I keep getting the same output.

Comment: @PallaviSingh Yes you have declared it in `main` but have you initialized it, I mean what is the value of `size`?

Comment: Yes, the size has to be user input and I have not added a scanf() statement for that. It'll run once I do that.

Comment: @PallaviSingh If that works then do visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers